# Laravel 5.2 Модель возвращает свойства из списка hidden

Tags: php, laravel

Добавил в модель `User` свойство `$hidden = ['password'];`
Но при получении модели это поле все равно подтягивается, что я делаю не так?

Comment: свойство protected?

Comment: Покажите, как вы получаете модель. Свойство спрятано от массивов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем случае, вот правильный способ спрятать поле:

Модель:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

     protected $hidden = array('password');

}
```

Файл `route.php`

```
Route::get('users', function() {
     return User::all()->toArray();
});
```

Свойства `password` в массиве не будет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, на самом деле это проблема когда пытаюсь автоматически заполнить Collective генератор форм используя `Form::model()`